# Websockets client not returning the data in Firefox

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, mern

Created a chat application, i have used websockets in it.

```
[...wss.clients].forEach((client) => {
    client.send(
      JSON.stringify({
        online: [...wss.clients].map((c) => ({
          userId: c.userId._id,
          userName: c.userId.userName,
        })),
      })
    );
```

This code sends userId and username in edge successfully but in firefox, it returns undefined.

When I console logged the request data then I found that in Edge the userId and userName are included in the request data but in firefox they are not included.

Comment: That seem browser specific issue, check your settings if you aren't blocking something you shouldn't.